# What JavaScript syntax highlighter does GitHub use?

Tags: javascript, github, syntax-highlighting

What syntax highlighter is GitHub using on their site to display the code when you click on the file names?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [this help page](https://help.github.com/articles/my-repository-is-marked-as-the-wrong-language/) of GitHub.com says, they’re using the [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist), which is written in Ruby.

Linguist’s highlighters for each language are within [`vendor/grammars`](https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/master/vendor/grammars). And a list of supported languages can be found [here](https://github.com/jmm/gfm-lang-ids/wiki/GitHub-Flavored-Markdown-(GFM)-language-IDs), [here](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml), and [here](https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/master/vendor).

Comment: Can we use linguist as a syntax highlighter? Their one seems the most comprehensive.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai what do you mean by "we"? If you want to propose it for Stack Exchange, you should post it on meta.

Comment: I meant in generic we, as me.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I'm not sure what your question is. Of course you can use, it's open source and the license is included in the repository.

Comment: ...which is server-side. You might want to add that in the response; it doesn't use Javascript, but rather Ruby on the server to add the appropriate CSS classes.

Comment: This finds a grammar file, but what is the program that actually takes this grammar and my code and outputs my code with the appropriate markup for color? It looks like Linguist doesn't do that step.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is wrong. I'm pretty sure Linguist doesn't _do_ the syntax highlighting, it just _determines_ the language so the syntax highlighter can then go do its job according to that language. So, what's the syntax highlighter?

Comment: It doesn't do syntax highlighting, it only detects the language, I explored the repository alot. The grammars specify the text-mate scopes, which are not used by the linguist.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub uses [tree-sitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) grammars for syntax highlighting the following languages: CSS, Go, **JavaScript**, EJS, ERB, HTML, Python, Ruby, TypeScript and CodeQL. The JavaScript tree-sitter grammar is here: https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-javascript ([grammar.js](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-javascript/blob/master/grammar.js) and [src/scanner.c](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-javascript/blob/master/src/scanner.c) are the important files)

Source: https://github.com/github/linguist/discussions/5572#discussioncomment-1355712